# Netbeans Spring Boot Initilizr project: Unable to see jsp content in web browser

Tags: java, maven, jsp, spring-mvc, netbeans

I am reading Spring in Action, 4th Edition by manning publications and Chapter 5 is about Spring Web App. I am trying to implement textbook example in Netbeans using Maven template Spring Boot Initilizr Project. (Examples by author use Gradle. I want to use Maven Project Management tool) 
[image: Maven => Spring Boot Initilizr Project]

However when I am trying to see content in browser, I am getting "Whitelabel Error Page". Below is my project configuration. What should I do to get past the error in Web browser and see content present in home.jsp

[image: My Project Configuration]

WebConfig.java content:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("spitter.web")
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
        public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver
            = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setExposeContextBeansAsAttributes(true);
        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(
            DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

}
```

home.jsp content:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ page session="false" %>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Spittr</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet"
              type="text/css"
              href="<c:url value="/resources/style.css" />" >
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Welcome to Spittr</h1>
        <a href="<c:url value="/spittles" />">Spittles</a> |
        <a href="<c:url value="/spitter/register" />">Register</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am able to properly test @Test scripts present in Test Packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now realized that the issue id with how I setup the project. Book example (Spring Web MVC) is a web application and not a Spring Boot application. Spring boot applications are standalone applications that require `public static void main (String[] args)` to be present. However Spring Web MVC application which displays .jsp pages is expected to run on server. Hence below template of Netbeans is more relevant

[image]

Once this template is chosen, rest of tasks are simple. Also, the book example incorrectly coded `spittr` as `spitter` in couple of places. That needs to be corrected as well as has been mentioned in book forum - https://forums.manning.com/posts/list/38046.page;jsessionid=8A9B66613EC5B4CAB91E1897C5631970. Once these are corrected, application should run fine. Below is my project structure

[image]

WebConfig with corrected package name is

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("spittr.web")
public class WebConfig
    extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver
                = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
            resolver.setExposeContextBeansAsAttributes(true);
            return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(
            DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }
}
```

RootConfig with corrected package name:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"spittr"},
    excludeFilters = {
        @Filter(type = FilterType.ANNOTATION, value = EnableWebMvc.class)
    })
public class RootConfig {
}
```